# adding error bars and significance bars to binary data ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, errorbar

I have the following dataset:

```
df <- data.frame(replicate(2,sample(0:1,30,rep=TRUE)))
df <- reshape(data=df, varying=list(1:2), 
        direction="long", 
        times = names(df), 
        timevar="Type",
        v.names="Score")
```

and to create a bargraph I use

```
ggplot(df ,aes(x=Score, fill = Type))+
  geom_bar(position="dodge", color="black")
```

which gives us

[image]

I want to add error bars similar to

[image]

for graded data I would just use add = "mean_ci", but adding it to this function does nothing

```
ggplot(df ,aes(x=Score, fill = Type), add = "mean_ci")+
  geom_bar(position="dodge", color="black")
```

[image]

How do I get nice error bars for my binary data bargraph?

additionally I would also like to add significance bars so the bargraph ultimately looks similar to the following

[image]

However I cannot figure out how to go about it with a dataset that looks like the one I have above.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the original df, just create another dataframe using table, and compute the count and sd from there. binomial variable so using variance defined as np(1-p) here:

```
df <- data.frame(replicate(2,sample(0:1,30,rep=TRUE)))
df1 <- reshape(data=df, varying=list(1:2), 
              direction="long", 
              times = names(df), 
              timevar="Type",
              v.names="Score")

t1 <- as.data.frame(table(df$X1))
t1$Type <- "X1"
t1$sd <- sqrt(sum(t1$Freq)*t1$Freq/sum(t1$Freq)*(1-t1$Freq/sum(t1$Freq)))
t2 <- as.data.frame(table(df$X2))
t2$Type <- "X2"
t2$sd <- sqrt(sum(t2$Freq)*t2$Freq/sum(t2$Freq)*(1-t2$Freq/sum(t2$Freq)))
df_tbl <- rbind(t1,t2)
names(df_tbl) <- c("Score","count","Type","sd")
df_tbl$marg <- df_tbl$count + df_tbl$sd + 1
                            
y0 <- max(df_tbl[which(df_tbl$Score==0),'marg'])
y1 <- max(df_tbl[which(df_tbl$Score==1),'marg'])
prob0 <- prop.test(c(nrow(df)-sum(df$X1), nrow(df)-sum(df$X2)), c(nrow(df), nrow(df)))
prob1 <- prop.test(c(sum(df$X1), sum(df$X2)), c(nrow(df), nrow(df)))
prob <- c(prob0$p.value, prob1$p.value)
prob_sig <- as.character(cut(prob,breaks=c(-1,0.0005,0.001,0.01,max(prob)),
                       labels=c("***","**","*","NS")))

ggplot(df_tbl, aes(x=Score, y=count, fill=Type)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", color="black", 
           position=position_dodge()) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=count-sd, ymax=count+sd), width=.2,
                position=position_dodge(.9)) +
  ylim(c(0,max(df_tbl$count+df_tbl$sd)+4)) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = 0.8, xend = 1.2, y = y0, yend = y0)) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = 1.8, xend = 2.2, y = y1, yend = y1)) +
  geom_text(aes(x = 1, y = y0 + 0.5, label=prob_sig[1])) +
  geom_text(aes(x = 2, y = y1 + 0.5, label=prob_sig[2]))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your useful answer, however I do not really understand what is going on after "df_tbl$marg" and everything regarding the significance bars - what I am looking for is a way to compare the proportions of x1 and x2 0s, and x1 and x2 1s to see if they differ significantly (something similar to stat_compare_means but for binary data. Ideally, also with solid significance bars that have 'hooks' at the end.

Comment: @Icewaffle For that you'll have to do prop.test. I updated the code to use the right probability values. You can't exactly do errorbars (with 'hooks') for those, since you are doing intergroup comparison. Either insert those hooks manually through another geom_segment, or choose lineshape etc. so that they are distinguishable. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, very useful! One final question - do these error bars represent standard deviation or confidence interval? I forgot to specify it, but I am looking for confidence interval.

Comment: @Icewaffle I used std. deviation, but to get 95% confidence interval, you can do `ymin=count-1.96*sd/sqrt(nrow(df)), ymax=count+1.96*sd/sqrt(nrow(df))` inside geom_errorbar.